# How to "repo init" on a disconnected system?

Tags: repository

I have mirrored a repository with

```
repo init -u <uri of manifest> --mirror
repo sync
```

and copied it (by usb) to a system disconnected from the internet along with the repo script and the repo clone bundle repository from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle.

I now want to create new client from the mirror, but when I run the command.

```
repo init -u <uri of manifest on mirror>
```

i get the following error.

```
fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

So I have the clone.bundle but have no way to persuade repo to use it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an option, that appears to be totaly undocumented on the internet for repo. It is --repo-url which allows you to overide where repo looks for the latest version of itself.

This is what I did:

I had the bundle saved in my home as git-repo-clone.bundle

```
repo init -u < uri of manifest on mirror > --repo-url ~/git-repo-clone.bundle
```

I found this out by reading the repo script itself, and thought I would share.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to ignore the clone bundle.

```
repo init -u <your-manifest-mirror-url> --no-clone-bundle
```